# Error occurred while updating my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My PC was running low on space and Windows recommended me to add an external USB drive in order to complete the updation process to version 20H2. I started downloading the update, and when it hit 100%, it gave 'Download error' and now when I click 'Retry', it starts all the way from 1%.

I still have the folder named *WUDownloadCache* in my USB drive occupying around 3.9 GB space. Is there a way to use that folder to update my system? Or, do I need to start all over again from 0%?

Comment: You will likely have to run the process again. Run Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup, select the option to clean up System Files. Wait for it to present selections and select all of them. Run it, restart and try again.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it will suck, to have the whole process run again. Anyway, I guess there is no other way. So I have to do it.

Comment: It will also run far faster from SSD or even a slower HDD than from flash USB. Before running *any* update, clean up trash.